# How to redirect if not root route to subdirectory index file with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, server, url-rewriting

I have two web pages.
I want to deploy these two pages on one domain.
When I call the root URL, I want to load the `index.html` in root directory, and for other URLs, I want to load the `index1.html` in the `/app` directory.

This is the directory structure.

```
www.example.com/index.html
www.example.com/app/index1.html
```

For example:
when request `www.example.com`
loading `index.html`

For `www.example.com/login`
loading `/app/index1.html`

For `www.example.com/signup`
loading `/app/index1.html`

This is what I have tried.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/index1.html [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This make redirection when I request `www.example.com/signup` to `www.example.com/app/index1.html`.

But I want to load `app/index1.html` without redirection. Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following .htaccess rules. Please make sure of following things before you test your URLs:

- Make sure your `.htaccess` file, `index.html` and your `app` folder are residing in same `root` folder.
- Make sure you have `index1.html` file present inside `/app` folder.
- Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rule from OP's attempt to block direct access of index.html file.
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [NC,L]

##Rule to handle only url www.example.com here.
RewriteRule ^/?$  /index.html [QSA,NC,L]

##Rules to handle rest of the cases here..
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^  /app/index1.html [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: "Rule from OP's attempt to block direct access of index.html file." - That rule does not "block direct access to index.html". That line is an "optimisation" (to prevent unnecessary filesystem checks), except that it is incorrect as written so isn't providing much benefit. It should match the rewritten URL (primarily `/app/index1.html`), so should be something like this instead: `RewriteRule (^|/)index1?\.html$ - [L]` (to match both `/index.html` and `/app/index1.html`). (Although the "rewrite" to `/index.html` should really be handled by mod_dir, ie. `DirectoryIndex`.)

Comment: @MrWhite, thank you for your comment. I agree with your regex even I was thinking to cover both html files. But IMHO the rule actually blocks access to them in very simple language correct? So that's why I had written like that, though I agree with your statement 

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>   RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteBase /
>   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/index1.html [R=301,L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

You basically just needed to remove the `R` (`redirect`) flag on the last `RewriteRule` directive. But this can be optimised:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^app/index1\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . app/index1.html [L]
```

mod_dir (ie. `DirectoryIndex`) serves `/index.html` from the root. This may already be configured in the server config, so the `DirectoryIndex` directive may not be required here.

- The first `RewriteRule` directive is an optimisation to prevent unnecessary filesystem checks. This should match the file being rewritten to. ie. `/app/index1.html` (not `/index.html`).
- The last `RewriteRule` matches against a single character (ie. `.` - dot) so excludes requests for the root directory so prevents unnecessary filesystem checks everytime the root is requested. The regex `^(.*)$` on the other hand matches *everything*, including the root (which fails the directory check - 2nd *condition* / `RewriteCond` directive).
- Unless you are using symlinks then you can remove the 3rd *condition*.
- Depending on the format of your URLs then you could make the regex more restrictive and perhaps remove the first *condition* that checks that the request does not map to a file (filesystem checks are relatively expensive). eg. Do your URLs contain dots? The two examples you gave do not. Dots naturally delimit file extensions, so if your URLs do not contain dots then they will naturally not map to any existing files.